# Как защитить телеграм бот от атаки ботнета и в принципе DDos атак?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot, ddos

владею в телеграме ботом, а точнее магазином цифровых товаров. Бот написан на python. Тип связи с телеграм серверами Polling. Как переводить на вебхуки не разбираюсь.
И недавно один шутник запустил ботнет на моего бота, это все решилось обычной перезагрузкой, но мне стало интересно что если вдруг будет серьезная атака, то мой бот будет просто беззащитный. Как вообще можно защитить бота от ботнета и в принципе DDos-атак?

Comment: Например проверять количество запросов к боту с одного id, не ip

Comment: у Вас получилось решить? Если да, то подскажите как)